# Redux testing using jest

Tags: reactjs, react-native, enzyme, jestjs

I am trying to test react-navigation stateless component that uses redux as below

```
import 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import toJson from 'enzyme-to-json';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import AppNavigator, { mapStateToProps } from '../../src/navigation';
import { Pages } from '../../src/data';

const nav = { routeName: Pages.AFFIRMATION };

describe('Testing App Navigation', () => {
    let state = null;
    it('renders as expected', () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(
            <AppNavigator store={createStore(() => nav)} />
        );
        expect(toJson(wrapper)).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
});
```

The AppNavigator component looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { addNavigationHelpers } from 'react-navigation';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Navigator } from './routes';

const AppNavigator = ({ dispatch, nav }) => (
    <Navigator navigation={addNavigationHelpers({ dispatch, state: nav })} />
);

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    nav: state.nav,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AppNavigator);
```

Challenge when i check code coverage `npm test -- --coveraage` I realiase that this line (11) `<Navigator navigation={addNavigationHelpers({ dispatch, state: nav })} />` and the function calling it are uncovered.

[image: line 11 is uncovered]

What am I missing, why is line 11 uncovered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was separate the AppNnavigator function into a different file and then do the tests